# Places API android not showing on specific device

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to create a location based notification for an app I'm working on. I get a location using Google Places API and create a location based notification like so:

```
//used to get places
private void showPlaces() {
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        displayPlace(PlacePicker.getPlace(getContext(), data));
    }
}

private void displayPlace(Place place)
{
    if (place == null)
        return;

    double latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
    double longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;

    if (ingredient_list.size() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Display Place:");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{ android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{ android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Display Place:");
        initGoogleAPIClient();
        createGeofences(latitude, longitude);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Added Notification!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void initGoogleAPIClient()
{
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionAddListener)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionAddListener = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks()
{
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
            {
                System.out.println("onConnected");
                try{
                    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                            mGoogleApiClient,
                            getGeofencingRequest(),
                            getGeofencePendingIntent()
                    ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status)
                        {
                            if (status.isSuccess())
                            {
                                System.out.println("Saving Geofence");
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Registering geofence failed: " + status.getStatusMessage() + " : " + status.getStatusCode());
                                }
                        }
                    });

                }
                catch (SecurityException securityException)
                {
                    // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
                    System.out.println("Error " + securityException);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
            {
                System.out.println("onConnectionSuspended");
            }
        };

private GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener connectionFailedListener =
        new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
            {
                System.out.println("onConnectionFailed");
            }
        };

public void createGeofences(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Geofence fence = new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(id)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 200)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .build();
    mGeofenceList.add(fence);
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest()
{
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent()
{
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null)
    {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra("extra", title_string);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("extra2", ingredient_list);
    return PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

This seems to work fine on every device I tested on except for a user testing on a Nexus 5 6.0.1 who reports that when he launches a notification request, the map shows briefly and then disappears immediately after that. I initially thought that this might have something to do with the permission so I asked him to manually turn on his location permission in the app settings but he got the same result. Does anyone have a clue as to whats going on here? I can't seem to figure out why it works on multiple other devices even on the same firmware but it's not showing up for him.

Comment: check your target SDK and dangerous permissions. It might be causing the problem.

Comment: Sadly no results with that. I've also tried turning off the location permission manually and I can still view the place picker. The user has the required permission, he sees the place picker momentarily and then it immediately closes on him.

Comment: What is your target SDK? have you implemented dangerous permission flow if it is > API 22 ?

Comment: More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html